# Spresenseカメラボードについて

Tags: spresense

10センチ以内の近距離写真を取りたいですが、ピントが合わないためレンズ部品を探しています。
対応するレンズ部品はありますか？

また、Spresenseメインボードは他のカメラモジュール（Arducamやpi cameraなど）との接続は可能ですか？

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow は”当サイトでは、コーディングやアルゴリズムなど、主にプログラミングに関する問題のサポートを目標としています。”となっていますので、部品等の問い合わせは、メーカや購入店に問い合わせた方がいいと思います。

外部のレンズは広角（魚眼）のものはあっても、マクロ用はないようですね。
https://products.entaniya.co.jp/products/vr-220-camera-for-spresense/